# Powershell - Piping multiple disk drives into separate variables

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to set up some slack alerts for our Windows servers. Learning a little bit about PowerShell I've created a simple script that will send a slack message once the disk space of the specified drive has passed the remaining disk space threshold.

My question and after scouring online after running - `Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk`the output reports back multiple disk drives such as "C:" "D:" "E:" etc. I want the script to be intuitive enough to be able to find these disk drives and automatically place them in their own variable without having the administrator having to edit the script's `$driveletter` variable each and every time they utilize the script.

Is this possible?

```
# Configuration Variables for slack and free disk space capacity threshold to send slack messsage
$slackUrl           = "SOME SLACK CHANNEL URL"
$slackBotName       = "*Diskspace Bot*"
$slackWarningMsg    = "*Critical* :fire:"
$WarningThresholdGB = 80

# Get disk information. 
$driveLetter  = "C:"
$diskInfo     = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$driveLetter'"  |Select-Object DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size
$diskName     = $diskInfo.DeviceID 
$diskGBFree   = $diskInfo.FreeSpace
$diskCapacity = $diskInfo.Size

# Convert to GiB
$diskGBFree     = [math]::Round($diskGBFree / 1GB)
$diskGBCapacity = [math]::Round($diskCapacity / 1GB)
$diskGBUsed     = [math]::Round($diskGBCapacity - $diskGBFree)

# Checks to see if free diskspace threshold has been reached, if so, send a message to slack

If ($diskGBFree -lt $WarningThresholdGB) {

$slackMessage = @{
text = "
$slackBotName
$slackWarningMsg
*Location:* $env:computername
*Drive Name:* $diskName Drive
*Low disk space Alert:* $diskGBUsed GB / $diskGBCapacity GB 
"
}

Invoke-Webrequest `
    -Uri $slackUrl `
    -Method Post `
    -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $slackMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you an array of Disks with low space that you can then step through and report from:

```
$lowspaceDisks = @()

foreach($disk in Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk){
    If($disk.Size){ #check to see if size > 0
        if(($disk.FreeSpace / $disk.Size) -lt 0.2){  #check for low disk space
            $lowDisk = [pscustomobject]@{   #create object with desired parameters
                "diskName"=$disk."DeviceID";
                "diskGBUsed"=[math]::Round(($disk.Size - $disk.FreeSpace) / 1GB);
                "diskGBCapacity"=[math]::Round($disk.Size / 1GB)
                }
            $lowspaceDisks += $lowDisk  #add object to array
        }
    }
}
```

To see the results after running in the ISE just type the variable `$lowspaceDisks`

Or your Slack code might look like this:  (I'm not a slack user yet.)

```
foreach($disk in Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk){
    If($disk.Size){ #check to see if size > 0
        if(($disk.FreeSpace / $disk.Size) -lt 0.2){  #check for low disk space
                $diskName=$disk."DeviceID";
                $diskGBUsed=[math]::Round(($disk.Size - $disk.FreeSpace) / 1GB);
                $diskGBCapacity=[math]::Round($disk.Size / 1GB)


                $slackMessage = @{
                text = "
                $slackBotName
                $slackWarningMsg
                *Location:* $env:computername
                *Drive Name:* $diskName Drive
                *Low disk space Alert:* $diskGBUsed GB / $diskGBCapacity GB 
                "
                }

                Invoke-Webrequest `
                    -Uri $slackUrl `
                    -Method Post `
                    -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $slackMessage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I'll give this a go and report back but this will get me started on the right direction :D

Comment: @ttruong Cool.  If it works or helps enough please flag as correct answer, or let me know other road blocks you hit.